# ElementTree.ParseError while downloading NLTK Corpus

Tags: python, nltk, elementtree, centos7

I have installed `nltk 3.2.1` on my CentOS machine.
Now whenever I try to download any corpora/models of NLTK, it gives me below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 2268, in <module>
halt_on_error=options.halt_on_error)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 664, in download
for msg in self.incr_download(info_or_id, download_dir, force):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 534, in incr_download
try: info = self._info_or_id(info_or_id)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 508, in _info_or_id
return self.info(info_or_id)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 875, in info
self._update_index()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 825, in _update_index
ElementTree.parse(compat.urlopen(self._url)).getroot())
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
tree.parse(source, parser)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
parser.feed(data)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
self._raiseerror(v)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 49
```

Note that I have tried all the below methods to download NLTK data -

- `nltk.download()`
- `nltk.download('all')`
- `python -m nltk.downloader all`

But in all the methods I receive the same error.
Anybody has any idea why I am getting this error and how to download NLTK data?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see: Your downloader opens the xml document that lists the available downloads, tries to parse it, and gets an error:

```
ElementTree.parse(compat.urlopen(self._url)).getroot())
```

Either (very unlikely) the nltk site is no longer compatible with Python 2.7, or you're not actually receiving the expected XML document because there's something wrong with your connection. Are you [behind a proxy?](http://www.nltk.org/data.html#installing-via-a-proxy-web-server) If not, something else is probably wrong with your connection.

Comment: I am not behind proxy. Your suggestion is right, it is not able to get the expected XML Document. Actually in the downloader you can see that the Server Index is `http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/` and in my machine the `git` commands are not working. It is throwing `Issuer certificate is invalid` error.

Comment: I don't know where you saw that. The downloader index file is fetched from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml`. As you see, it's an `http(s)` service, not `git`. Inspect it with your favorite browser. Better yet, tell the nltk to fetch it and see if you can identify the problem.